# How did Starbucks, Fuddruckers, and Carl's Jr. respond to Idiocracy?

Tags: idiocracy, product-placement

In the movie [*Idiocracy* (2006)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0387808/), several real-life name brands are made fun of.  The three I remember:

- Starbucks gives hand jobs
- Fuddruckers changes its name to "Buttf***ers"
- Carl's Jr. changes its slogan from "Don't bother me, I'm eating" to "F**k you! I'm eating."

Did the makers of *Idiocracy* make any effort to get permission to use these brand names? If not, have any of these companies expressed disapproval?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, the production staff lawyered up real well. From a [Slashfilm interview with Mike Judge](http://www.slashfilm.com/the-mike-judge-interview-part-2-gene-simmons-and-ben-affleck-in-extract-corporate-product-hilarity-in-idiocracy-and-the-kamikaze-futures-of-beavis-butt-head/):

> And as far as the products stuff, I remember writing it and going, “Oh
>   man, there’s no way we’re going to clear all of this stuff.” And I had
>   a meeting with the lawyers, who were actually really cool and really
>   liked the script. [laughs] And in the Beavis & Butt-Head movie I
>   couldn’t even have a bottle that was shaped like a Jack Daniel’s
>   bottle. I couldn’t have, there was more, it was just ridiculous on
>   that [movie].
>
> But on Idiocracy, when we were talking about Starbucks, the lawyers
>   said, “Well, it would help if you didn’t pick on just one company and
>   if you did more than one.” So, [laughs] I was like okay, and that’s
>   why there’s the whole red light district with Starbucks and there’s an
>   H&R Block with “Tax Return and Relief,” and all of that. But the other
>   stuff, Carl Jr’s, that was all in the script, and I couldn’t believe
>   it all cleared.

Second, it wasn't high profile enough to cause the companies any big issues (from the same interview):

> At one point, [Fox] told me, “Hey, it’s not testing well, we’re not
>   going to spend a lot of money promoting it.”